# Rightclick event on main page of Silverlight 3 application?

Tags: silverlight

I want to trigger an event when user Right-click on the page, let's say I want to navigate to another page on Rightclick down event.

Can any one help on this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explained at the following Post.Click [here](http://blog.subhendu.info/index.php/rightclick-event-on-main-page-of-silverlight-3-application/).

Answer (score 0):

This feature is only available in SL 4, sorry.